# focus() not working on transitioned element

Tags: javascript, jquery

An input box which is shown after clicking on search icon in Header Section is not getting focus. Following code has been tried:

```
jQuery('.top-bar-section .search-form').toggleClass('shown').focus();
```

also,

```
$( ".top-bar-section .search-button" ).click(function() {
  $( ".top-bar-section .search-field" ).focus();
});
```

class .shown is added when user click on icon.

[Example in header section of live url](http://www.satya-weblog.com/)

Comment: I don't think your jquery is being loaded at all - `<script type='text/rocketscript' data-rocketsrc='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>` - `console.log($)` gives me `undefined` as well

Comment: No, jquery is getting loaded but $ is not an obj. I use jQuery. I quickly added in in theme option to test and missed to use jQuery. Now, I see 2nd code is working. Thanks.

Comment: Still a problem! When there is data inside it, then it don't work. 1. I searched something, then it leads to new page. 2. I again click on icon button on header. This time, focus() is not going there.

Comment: I'd say there's focus stealing issue somewhere on the page - maybe with the googleads?

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery( ".top-bar-section .search-button" ).click(function() {
  var _int = window.setTimeout(function(){
     if (jQuery(".top-bar-section .search-field").is(":focus"))
         window.clearTimeout(_int);
     jQuery( ".top-bar-section .search-field" ).focus(); }, 100);
}); });` should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you, for your code. I see locally, if I remove the code `focus()` from `jQuery('.top-bar-section .search-form').toggleClass('shown');` and add separate line for `focus()` then it is working. I think, `focus()` is getting executed before input is shown on browser and so the problem. Can it be the case?

Comment: I thought it is with googleads, as even when calling the event assignment from the console, the focus wouldn't run. It might be also connected to JS errors. Truly, I don't know - it would require commenting stuff out atp to find out.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Problem is solved. I checked again if it is working and it is working.